# Changing the encoding of a table with django+south migrations using --auto

Tags: python, django, django-south

Django newbie here

I know that I can change the encoding of a table by writing my own south migration.

My question is, is there a way doing it by changing my model and using

```
./manage.py schemamigration my_app --auto
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such thing as charset modification migration, as charset depends on deployment and thus is settings option.

Thus, You must crate the migration manually (so probably without `--auto` and using raw SQL).